# Add custom post type taxonomy tag to article class

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

Ok, so I have tried about 5 different WP functions now and no luck. Basically here is what I want to do. I have a custom post type called "work", I have a taxonomy within this custom post type called "type" with 2 types available.. "Case Study" & "Portfolio". Depending on which option is checked off I would like that to print in the class of my container for that item and also be converted to lower case with spaces replaced by underscores.

```
<aside class="work_item <?php has_term('Portfolio', 'type'); ?>" data-type="<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?>">
```

That is what I have now but no luck.. I have tried:

has_term
get_the_terms
get_term

and no luck... been looking at this so long now feel like I am missing something dumb

Desired output:

```
<aside class="work_item case_study" data-type="<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?>">
```

&

```
<aside class="work_item portfolio" data-type="<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?>">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, solved it!

```
<aside class="work_item <?php $posttags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type'); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?>" data-type="<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach ($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?>">
```

had to use the get_the_terms() function